# Capturing the "progress bar" shown in a terminal

Tags: command-line, text-processing, scp

I am looking for the "verbose" output of `scp`, as shown by the following command, but excluding all lines containing `debug1:`:

```
scp -v /path/to/some_very_large_file user@host:/home/user/test.deleteme 2>&1
```

As you should see, after a short time `scp` starts displaying a progress line that updates frequently.

This command is intended to be called from within a bash script, and keeping progress output is desired. However can someone explain why is the progress indication lost when this command is piped so?:

```
scp -v /path/to/some_very_large_file user@host:/home/user/test.deleteme 2>&1 | grep -v 'debug1:'
```

Any ideas about a workaround are also welcome; this is with Ubuntu 16.02.2 LTS.

Comment: Well-behaved commands like scp print a user-friendly, updating progress bar when the output is connected to a terminal, and don't do that when the output is not to connected to a terminal, because then there's no guarantee that the progress bar will make any sense in the output. But if you don't want debug messages, why would you use `-v`? That's the whole point of `-v`:  " Verbose mode.  Causes scp and ssh(1) to print **debugging** messages about their progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems."

Comment: Option -v outputs more than debug information, or more precisely it generates also lines not starting with the debug tag which are interesting to look at. For example connection handshaking and progress... Basically I'd like to see any information relevant to the progress of the call, and would like to exclude the 'purely debug' portion.